# Chained Arrow Function in Redux Syntax

Tags: redux, react-redux, arrow-functions

Hi I'm just working into Redux and currently I'm just confused about a redux syntax given in a Redux-Cheat-Sheet [Redux Cheat Sheet from Egghead](https://github.com/linkmesrl/react-journey-2016/blob/master/resources/egghead-redux-cheat-sheet-3-2-1.pdf):

```
const actionLogger = ({dispatch, getState}) =>
 (next) => (action) =>
 { console.log(action); return next(action) }
```

So my question is: What does this "chained" arrow functions behave like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write it down as:

```
const actionLogger = function({dispatch, getState} /* this is store object */) {
  return function(next) {
    return function(action) {
      console.log(action);
      return next(action);
    };
  };
};
```

So basically chained arrow functions represent nested functions. It could be a bit confusing.

[Detailed explanation how redux middleware works](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/Middleware.html)

Comment: So what I'm still confused is, where do dispatch and getState end up in this nested functions?

Comment: In fact, the only argument passed to the first function is the `store`. The example uses [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to get `dispatch` and `getState` methods. You can use them in the last function where you `return next(action)` but usually you don't need to use `dispatch` because it will trigger new action instead you should use `next`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use an arrow function:

```
const actionLogger = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
    console.log(getState())
   ......
};
```